# New object instances, generator, array, name generation

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, object, generator

Context: I'm building an Agent Based Model real estate market sim. I have household objects that have properties and methods and so far I have created them like this:

```
var houseHoldArray = [];

var Household = function(name, house) {
    this.name = name;
    this.house = house.address;
    this.x = house.x;
    this.y = house.y;
    this.isHomeOwner = true;
    this.isSelling = false;

};

Household.prototype.draw = function() {
ellipse(this.x, this.y, 10, 10);
};

Household.prototype.determinMove = function() {
    if(random(0, 100) <= 75){
        this.isSelling = true;
    }
};

var household1 = new Household("Smith", house1);
var household2 = new Household("Black", house2);
var household3 = new Household("Johnson", house3);
var household4 = new Household("Williams", house4);
var household5 = new Household("Jones", house5);

houseHoldArray.push(household1, household2, household3, household4, household5);

household1.draw();
household2.draw();
household3.draw();
household4.draw();
household5.draw();
```

I now want to create a function, triggered upon clicking on a button, that would automatically create a certain number of new household instances and store them in the array as I will need to iterate through them later on with a for loop and perform certain actions depending on the state of their isSelling and isHomeowner properties.

**Question: how do I create a function that, upon the click of a button, will generate a certain amount of new `Houselhold` object instances and push them to the `houseHoldArray`?**

You may find a more efficient way to do this but in the end I want to have an array containing individual household information that will allow me to run something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < houseHoldArray.length; i++) {
    if houseHoldArray[i].isSelling {
        //do something
    } 
    houseHoldArray[i].determinMove() 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using "houseHold1, houseHold2", let's already use them as an array. Same with Houses. Like this:

```
var houseHoldArray = [];
var houses = [new House(), new House(), new House(), new House(), new House()];
function addHouseHolds(number, names, houseIndexes){
    for(var i = 0; i < number; i++){
        household = new Household(names[i],houses[ houseIndexes[i] ] );
        houseHoldArray.push(household);
    }
}
```

in html:

```
<button onclick='addHouseHolds(5, ["Smith", "Black", "Johnson","Williams","Jones"], [0,1,2,3,4] )'>Click me</button>
```